# How to update Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am currently running Inkscape 0.92 on my Windows 10 machine. Is there a way from within the interface to update InkScape? or do I have to manually download and install each and every version that comes out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Please uninstall, then install a new Inkscape version. This is also explained on the inkscape.org website.

(unless you installed Inkscape from the Windows store, I don't know how that upgrades)